# Find record with TAG LIST column duplicated

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a table like this

| KEY | TAGS |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A B C |
| 002 | D E |
| 003 | B C A |

VALUES Column contain a list of TAG with SPACES between tags.

I want to find all the Key with duplicated values, not depending from they order.

In my example, how can I find KEY 001 and 003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SPLIT`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/i/7.3?topic=services-split-table-function) and [`LISTAGG`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/i/7.3?topic=functions-listagg) to order the tags

```
WITH input_datas (key, tags) AS (
    VALUES
    ('001', 'A B C'),
    ('002', 'D E'),
    ('003', 'B C A')
),
key_tags AS (
    SELECT
        key, ELEMENT AS tag
    FROM
        input_datas
        CROSS JOIN TABLE (SYSTOOLS.SPLIT(tags, ' ')) AS tags
),
ordered_tags AS (
    SELECT
        key, LISTAGG(DISTINCT tag, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tag) tags
    FROM key_tags
    GROUP BY key
)
SELECT * FROM ordered_tags WHERE tags IN (SELECT tags FROM ordered_tags GROUP BY tags HAVING count(1) > 1)
```